# Viewer to open .CDR files

Tags: graphic-design

I have a few users here at my work that use the Corel Draw application to create certain types of Labels, etc.  In our engineering department, there are documentation specialists that need to open up some of these files and put the pictures into documents, manuals, etc. as well as grab the part numbers and other things.  The files have a .CDR file extension to them and I have searched the web for about 2 hours so far with no results.  I have downloaded about 20 apps that said they opened .cdr files (along with all the other extensions) and when I installed it and go to open a .cdr file, the application doesn't open it.  I've been on Corel's website and couldn't even find anything there.

Comment: Corel Draw is able to export to other file formats, ask them to do this for you or get one copy of Corel draw and convert it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a version problem with Corel? 
Go to the http://www.Corel.com/    website and download a trial of the latest version.

You can try doing it with Microsoft Word. 
As: Insert -> Picture -> From file.
May be this article will give you more information.
http://www.fixya.com/support/t25280540-corel_draw_x6_problems

Answer (score 5):

### Corel Draw

The official way to open CDR files is [Corel Draw](http://www.coreldraw.com/us/product/graphic-design-software/index-b.html?topNav=us&mboxSession=1453323603221-244404&s_tnt=79332:1:0) of course. Google hit number 7 for "cdr file" also [says this](http://www.coreldraw.com/us/pages/open-cdr-file/?pgid=12800183).

Since you have not tagged this [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), your colleagues use that software already and you use it at work in a company, it should just be a matter of some bosses decision to buy it (400 USD) in order to get the work done. If you spent 2 hours of searching and trying, you have already spent a lot of money.

The official version is X7. Usually you can buy older versions like X5 or X6 for a highly reduced rate. In Germany I'd go to [Pearl](http://www.pearl.de/), which offers an X6 special edition for 99 EUR.

### Inkscape

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) can open CDR files.

From the file dialog it claims support for versions 7 through X4. I have personally tested with a Corel Draw 9 file and at first glance, the result looks fine.

[image: Inkscape file open dialog]

Be aware that Inkscape does potentially not support as many features as Corel Draw. If you use special features in Corel Draw, those might get lost or result in unexpected issues.

Answer (score 1):

For a gratis solution it is worth considering [LibreOffice Draw](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/) which supports a number of the Corel Draw file formats out of the box.

Of course a "better" workflow might be to **require**, *as a part of the release process*, that all .cdr files must be accompanied by .svg format "illustration" files - then the original authors could check that such files accurately reflect what they intended.